# How to inherit the declarative in SQLAlchemy without setting the __tablename__?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using flask-sqlalchemy, I want to create some class to inherit the declarative class and add the `__bind_key__`. So that I can create some tables and inherit these binded class.

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Model1(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'

class Table1(Model1):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

But I got some troubles:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Class <class '__main__.Model1'> 
    does not have a     __table__ or __tablename__ specified 
    and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class.
```

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `__abstract__` flag:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Model1(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'

class Table1(Model1):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

Classes with `__abstract__` set to `True` are ignored by SQLAlchemy declarative ([docs here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html?highlight=abstract#abstract)). As a bonus, this enables you to add SQLAlchemy specific attributes (for example columns) to your `Model1`.